# Using monad for simple Haskell parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

### **TL;DR**

I'm trying to understand how this:

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy pred = PsrOf p
  where
    p (c:cs) | pred c = Just (cs, c)
    p _ = Nothing
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy pred = do
    c <- anyChar
    if pred c then return c else empty
```

### Context

This is a snippet from some lecture notes on Haskell parsing, which I'm trying to understand:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char
import Data.Functor
import Data.List

newtype Parser a = PsrOf (String -> Maybe (String, a))
    -- Function from input string to:
    --
    -- * Nothing, if failure (syntax error);
    -- * Just (unconsumed input, answer), if success.

dePsr :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (String, a)
dePsr (PsrOf p) = p

-- Monadic Parsing in Haskell uses [] instead of Maybe to support ambiguous
-- grammars and multiple answers.

-- | Use a parser on an input string.
runParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
runParser (PsrOf p) inp = case p inp of
                            Nothing -> Nothing
                            Just (_, a) -> Just a
                          -- OR: fmap (\(_,a) -> a) (p inp)

-- | Read a character and return. Failure if input is empty.
anyChar :: Parser Char
anyChar = PsrOf p
  where
    p "" = Nothing
    p (c:cs) = Just (cs, c)

-- | Read a character and check against the given character.
char :: Char -> Parser Char
-- char wanted = PsrOf p
--   where
--     p (c:cs) | c == wanted = Just (cs, c)
--     p _ = Nothing
char wanted = satisfy (\c -> c == wanted)   -- (== wanted)

-- | Read a character and check against the given predicate.
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy pred = PsrOf p
  where
    p (c:cs) | pred c = Just (cs, c)
    p _ = Nothing
-- Could also be:
-- satisfy pred = do
--     c <- anyChar
--     if pred c then return c else empty

instance Monad Parser where
    -- return :: a -> Parser a
    return = pure

    -- (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
    PsrOf p1 >>= k = PsrOf q
      where
        q inp = case p1 inp of
                  Nothing -> Nothing
                  Just (rest, a) -> dePsr (k a) rest
```

I understand everything up until the last bit of the Monad definition, specifically I don't understand how the following line returns something of type `Parser b` as is required by the `(>>=)` definition:

```
Just (rest, a) -> dePsr (k a) rest
```

It's difficult for me grasp what the Monad definition means without an example. Thankfully, we have one in the alternate version of the `satisfy` function, which uses do-notation (which of course means the Monad is being called). I really don't understand do-notation yet, so here's the desugared version of `satisfy`:

```
satisfy pred = do
    anyChar >>= (c ->
    if pred c then return c else empty)
```

So based on the first line of our `(>>=)`definition, which is

```
PsrOf p1 >>= k = PsrOf q
```

We have `anyChar` as our `PsrOf p1` and `(c -> if pred c then return c else empty)` as our `k`. What I don't get is how in `dePsr (k a) rest` that `(k a)` returns a `Parser` (at least it shold, otherwise calling `dePsr` on it wouldn't make sense). This is made more confusing by the presence of `rest`. Even if `(k a)` returned a `Parser`, calling `dePsr` would extract the underlying function from the returned `Parser` and pass `rest` to it as an input. This is definitely doesn't return something of type `Parser b` as required by the definition of `(>>=)`. Clearly I'm misunderstanding something somewhere.

Comment: Note that `dePsr (k a) rest` is inside the `q` function. The `q` function is not directly given as a result of `... >>= ...`. The result of `... >>= ...` is `PsrOf q`, not `q`.

Comment: Also, note that `k` has type `a -> Parser b` (this can be seen in the commented-out type signature). So, if you give `k` an `a` value, it will give you a `Parser b` value. This is why `k a :: Parser b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, Maybe this will help.  Let's start by puting some points back into `dePsr`.

```
dePsr :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (String, a)
dePsr (PsrOf p) rest = p rest
```

And let's also write out return: (NB I'm putting in all the points for clarity)

```
return :: a -> Parser a
return a = PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, a))
```

And now from the `Just` branch of the `(>>=)` definition

```
 Just (rest, a) -> dePsr (k a) rest
```

Let's make sure we agree on what every thing is:

- `rest` the string remaining unparsed after `p1` is applied
- `a` the result of applying `p1`
- `k :: a -> Parser b` takes the result of the previous parser and makes a new parser
- `dePsr` unwraps a `Parser a` back into a function `String -> Maybe (String, a)

Remember we will wrap this *back* into a parser again at the top of the function: `PsrOf q`

So in English bind `(>>=)` take a parser in `a` and a function from `a` to a parser in `b` and returns a parser in `b`.  The resulting parser is made by wrapping `q :: String -> Maybe (String, b)` in the Parser constructor `PsrOf`. Then `q`, the combined parser, take a `String` called `inp` and applies the function `p1 :: String -> Maybe (String,a)` that we got from pattern matching against the first parser, and pattern matches on the result. For an error we propagate `Nothing` (easy).  If the first parser had a result we have tow pieces of information, the still unparsed string called `rest` and the result `a`. We give `a` to `k`, the second parser combinator, and get a `Parser b` which we need to unwrap with `dePsr` to get a function (`String -> Maybe (String,b)` back.  That function can be applied to `rest` for the final result of the combined parsers.

I think the hardest part about reading this is that sometimes we [curry](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) the parser function which obscures what is actually happening.

Ok for the `satisfy` example

```
satisfy pred 
  = anyChar >>= (c -> if pred c then return c else empty)
```

`empty` comes from the alternative instance and is `PsrOf (const Nothing)` so a parser that always fails.

Lets look at only the successful branches. By substitution of only the successful part:

```
PsrOf (\(c:cs) ->Just (cs, c)) >>= (\c -> PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, c)))
```

So in the bind `(>>=)` definition

- `p1 = \(c:cs -> Just (cs, c))`
- `k = (\c -> PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, c)))`
- `q inp = let Just (rest,a) = p1 inp in dePsr (k a) rest` again only successful branch

Then `q` becomes

```
q inp = 
  let Just (rest, a) = (\(c:cs) -> Just (cs, c)) inp
   in dePsr (\c -> PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, c))) a rest
```

Doing a little β-reduction

```
q inp =
 let (c:cs) = inp
     rest = cs
     a = c
  in dePsr (PsdOf (\rest -> Just (rest, a))) rest -- dePsr . PsrOf = id
```

Finally cleaning up some more

```
q (c:cs) = Just (cs, c)
```

So if `pred` is successful we reduce `satisfy` back to exactly `anyChar` which is exactly what we expect, *and* exactly what we find in the first example of the question. I will leave it as and exersize to the reader (read: I'm lazy) to prove that if either `inp = ""` or `pred c = False` that the outcome is `Nothing` as in the first `satisfy` example.

---

NOTE: If you are doing anything other than a class assignment, you will save yourself hours of pain and frustration by starting with error handling from the beginning make your parser `String -> Either String (String,a)` it is easy to make the error type more general later, but a PITA to change everything from `Maybe` to `Either`.

---

**Question:** "[C]ould you explain how you arrived at `return a = PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, a))` from `return = pure` after you put "points" back into return?

**Answer:** First off, it is pretty unfortunate to give the Monad instance definition without the Functor and Applicative definitions.  The `pure` and `return` functions must be identical (It is part of the Monad Laws), and they would be called the same thing except `Monad` far predates Applicative in Haskell history. In point of fact, I don't "know" what pure looks like, but I know what it has to be because it is the only possible definition. (If you want to understand the the proof of that statement ask, I have read the papers, and I know the results, but I'm not into typed lambda calculus quite enough to be confident in reproducing the results.)

`return` must wrap a value in the context *without* altering the context.

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
return :: a -> Parser a -- for our Monad
return :: a -> PsrOf(\str -> Maybe (rest, value)) -- substituting the constructor (PSUDO CODE)
```

A `Parser` is a function that takes a string to be parsed and returns `Just` the value along with any unparsed portion of the original string or `Nothing on failure, all wrapped in the constructor`PsrOf`.  The context is the string to be parsed, so we cannot change that. The value is of course what was passed to`return`. The parser always succeeds so we must return Just a value.

```
return a =  PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, a))
```

`rest` is the context and it is passed through unaltered.
`a` is the value we put into the Monad context.

For completeness here is also the only reasonable definition of `fmap` from Functor.

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b -- for Parser Monad
fmap f (PsrOf p) = PsrOf q
  where q inp = case p inp of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (rest, a) -> Just (rest, f a)
  -- better but less instructive definition of q
  -- q = fmap (\(rest,a) -> (rest, f a)) . p
```

Comment: I followed everything you wrote, but the main thing I was confused about is still the application of the monad in `satisfy`. You know how we have `k :: a -> Parser b`? In `satisfy`, if you look at the do-notation version commented out below, the `k` function matches with `(c -> if pred c then return c else empty)`. As you established, `k` should take in some `a` and return a `Parser b` but I don't see how it does that in this instance. There are only two outcomes: `return c` or `empty` (refers to the `Alternative` I believe) neither of which are of type `Parser b`.

Comment: The type of `return c` is `Monad m => m Char`, and the type of `empty` is `Alternative m => m Char`.  Because your `Parser` has both `Monad` (shown) and `Applicative` (not shown) instances, both these types unify with `Parser Char`, so the expression `if pred c then return c else empty` **DOES** have type `Parser Char`.

Comment: You haven't given the `Alternative` instance for `Parser` here: but I think it's helpful in this context to know that `empty` would be defined as `empty = PsrOf $ const Nothing` (that is, it's a "useless" parser that fails for every input - but such "useless" things have a mysterious way of ending up being very useful for defining abstract concepts). In particular, the `else empty` in the `do` block version corresponds exactly to the `p _ = Nothing` in the other version.

Comment: @John one last thing: could you explain how you arrived at `return a = PsrOf (\rest -> Just (rest, a))` from `return = pure` after you put "points" back into return? How can we assume to use `(\rest -> Just (rest, a))`? Also seriously, thanks for your responses. You've cleared up a lot.

Comment: @SakeebHossain, the definition of `pure` or `return` can be calculated from the definition of `>>=` (or even `<*>`, I believe). The monad identity laws `pure x >>= f = f x` and `m >>= pure = m` tell you all you need to know. Indeed, you only need one for the calculation. I think this time you're better off using the second law.